# Connection string in App.config changes when an Image is browsed

Tags: c#, connection-string, datasource

Below is the connection string inside app.config file.Notice the specified path in datasource.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="ConnString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data  Source=..\..\Database\ProductsDatabase.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

The application has an image control inside a button control with a MouseDoubleclick event.

```
                        <Button Name="m_oBtnProductImage" Grid.Column="0"  Height="60" Width="60" Background="LightGray" Style="{x:Null}" MouseDoubleClick="m_oBtnProductImage_MouseDoubleClick">
                                <Image Tag="Image" Name="m_oImage" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding SelectedProductEn.ProductImage}"></Image>
                        </Button>
```

The MouseDoubleclick event handler has functionality to browse and upload a new image and than update the same in database.

```
private void m_oBtnProductImage_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap oBitmapImage = null;
        OpenFileDialog oBrowseImageFile = new OpenFileDialog();
        oBrowseImageFile.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp";
        if (oBrowseImageFile.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            System.Windows.Controls.Image oPictureBox = ((Button)sender).FindName("m_oImage") as System.Windows.Controls.Image;
            string sImagePath = oBrowseImageFile.FileName;
            oBitmapImage = new Bitmap(sImagePath);
            ((CMainUIViewModel)this.DataContext).SelectedProductEn.ProductImage = (byte[])TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(oBitmapImage).ConvertTo(oBitmapImage, typeof(byte[]));
            ((CMainUIViewModel)this.DataContext).UpdateModifiedProduct(((CMainUIViewModel)this.DataContext).SelectedProductEn);
        }
    }
```

**When an image is browsed from application's UI,the path specified in the datasource changes to path of the browsed image file,thereby throwing an exception for not finding the database.**

Suggestions needed to make appropriate changes.

Comment: You're going to need to show exactly what m_oBtnProductImage_MouseDoubleClick is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution would be to set [RestoreDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.restoredirectory.aspx) to true:

```
oBrowseImageFile.RestoreDirectory = true;
if (oBrowseImageFile.ShowDialog())
{
    ...
}
```

A better solution is to avoid using a relative path in your connection string, e.g.

- use |DataDirectory| in your connection string
- call `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", somepath)` when your application starts up to set the location referenced by |DataDirectory|.  For example, you could set it to the directory containing your executable as follows:

  ```
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", 
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
  ```

Incidentally, `OpenFileDialog` implements `IDisposable`, so you should really call `IDisposable.Dispose`, probably with a `using` statement:

```
using (OpenFileDialog oBrowseImageFile = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    oBrowseImageFile.Filter = ...
    ... etc ...
}
```

Comment: @Joe.it works.Use of |DataDirectory| in the datasource did it.